# elasticsearch querying nested and wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to ask how will I "elasticsearch" query this data. For example, I want to get DATA with

```
"status": {"active":true}

{
  "P-0IpgVA": {
    "status": {
      "active": "true",
      "archived": 1517820757084,
      "listing_status": "Open",
      "updated": 1517820757084
    }
  },

  "P-04OOwC": {
    "status": {
      "active": 1519351623174,
      "archived": 1519351623174,
      "listing_status": "Open",
      "updated": 1519351784872
    }
  }
...
}
```

I tried this query but it does not work.

```js
"query": {
        "wildcard" : { "*" : { "status" : {"active": true}} }
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried :

```
{
  "query" : {
      "match" : {
        "status.active" : "true"
      }
    }
}
```

more details can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried but it does not show. @himanshu-chaudhary

Comment: I will recommend installing Kibana and try to compose your query from there. It will not only help to make meaningful queries but also help you understand the elastic syntax. If the above query did not worked then you might want to have a look at how are you pushing your data into elastic.